# Running ODOO 10 from eclipse on Windows 10 - missing information

Tags: python, eclipse, odoo, windows-10, odoo-10

Where is the odoo class and module defined? What should the pythonpath be?

I'm having problems setting up ODOO 10 community to run from Eclipse on Windows (10). This boils down to two problems: I can't find where the `odoo` class is defined so cannot import the odoo module,  and I don't know what the PYTHONPATH should be.

Details:

My main module in the Eclipse debug configuration is set to oddomain.py (renamed from odoo, in the setup folder) with the code:

```
# set server timezone in UTC before time module imported
# Israel time zone is IST so I'm hoping this will work
__import__('os').environ['TZ'] = 'IST'
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace('odoo.addons')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    odoo.cli.main()
```

I get: `missing odoo module from path`

I set up ODOO 10 community in eclipse on windows 10. I learned how to do it from comparing these posts:

- [Installing ODOO 10 Source](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/setup/install.html#setup-install-source),
- [How to debug ODOO in Eclipse in Debian](http://www.odoo.gotodoo.com/debug-odoo-eclipse/)
- and this old ​post: [How to debug ODOO in Eclipse under windows](https://www.odoo.com/forum/how-to/developers-13/how-to-debug-odoo-in-eclipse-under-winows-36105)

I'm running on MS Windows 10. 
I have eclipse with Pydev installed.
I have [the recommended](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/setup/install.html) python version (2.7.9) installed
I have the Postgres set up ok. (with BigSQL)
I have forked the odoo project on github and have the clone from github, locally.
I have the project set with the pydev nature.
I have all the packages installed by editing requirements.txt and running `pip install -r requirements.txt` in a cmd window in the odoo project directory.
I set up the odoo.conf with passwords for the postgres admin and odoo correctly.
I renamed the setup/odoo file to setup/odoomain.py and after reopening it in eclipse, it is recognized as python and I can set breakpoints. (calling it odoo.py was causing a problem, so I called it odoomain.py)
I set up the debug configuration of pydev to run the setup/odoomain.py as the main.

But I can't find the where the `odoo` class is defined, and therefore can't import the odoo module!  Where is it defined?

What should the PYTHONPATH for the project be? I set it in Eclipse:Project/Options)...

It is now set to

```
/$/PROJECT_DIR_Name)/odoo/addons
```

Where is the odoo module defined, and how do I import it? Is it something to do with the PYTHONPATH?

Comment: I still cannot find where the odoo class is defined. 

For the PythonPath it seems I need to only point to the root and remove all the other paths. So by me it should be only: /$(Project_Dir_Name)/addons  according to this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30833283/eclipse-pydev-how-to-install-python-modules|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the problem was twosome.

First of all I had to **correct the pythonpath** to include the root, and to include the odoo path. So now I have the PYTHONPATH set to 3 places.

- /$/PROJECT_DIR_Name)/odoo
- /$/PROJECT_DIR_Name)
- /$/PROJECT_DIR_Name)/odoo/addons

In order to determine the correct path,  you have to do "import odoo" in a python window from different paths (by changing directory in COMMAND window and running python again) and until it works, and set that

To set the pythonpath in eclipse:

```
Right-click on the project: 
    PyDev
        Set as Pydev Project 
Right-click on the project
    Properties
        PyDev - PYTHONPATH 
            Source Folders tab
                Add source folder
```

It works only if I add the root as the SECOND path, and only if all three are there.

Then I had to **correct my debug configuration** (by editing the "variable") as follows:  CORRECT

```
`--config=C:\MyPath\MyOdooProject\debian\odoo.conf`
```

Instead I had used the Browse and added the `--config` to get: WRONG

```
`--config=C:\MyPath\MyOdooProject\debian\`
```

And finally I had to run the Postgres on windows and connect to it in the PgAdmin. (I configured it already as requested and had the credentials listed in my debian/odoo.conf as explained.)

Everything runs ok now!! Thanks to Pham Tung for showing me the light!!

Comment: I also had to install nodejs on windows, and less (via node: npm install -g less or something more or less like that)

Comment: In Eclipse you need to rmb on project, Pydev, Set as Pydev proj. 

Then rmb on project, properties, pydev-pythonpath, add and remove to set it correctly. 

Also you need to rename the Setup/Odoo file to Setup/Odoo.py 

Double click it and check that the editor recognizes it as a python file. 

Last but not least, change the Debug or Run configuration to point to the odoomain.py

Comment: for resetting the Postgres admin password see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44586/forgotten-postgresql-windows-password

That's the admin pw you give in the debian/odoo.conf, there is no odoo.conf for windows...

Note: You must have an odoo user role (in pgAdmin you set it by right mouse button, properties and then Definition tab)  That's the database role and pw you give in the rest of the .conf file.